# Gas Estimation Error when Transfer ERC721 token in Remix

Tags: ethereum, transfer, remix

I am currently implementing an ERC721 token staking function contract, but when I add the transfer code, a Gas Estimation Error occurs.

`MarineBluesContract(_nftContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _tokenId);`

```
function stake(uint256 _tokenId, address _nftContract)
        external
        nonReentrant
    {
        require(ntfContractList[_nftContract], "Not allowed NFT contract");
        require(msg.sender != address(0), "Invalid staker address");
        require(_tokenId != 0, "Invalid token id");
        require(MarineBluesContract(_nftContract).ownerOf(_tokenId) == msg.sender, "Not token owner");

        // Staking start time
        uint48 timestamp = uint48(block.timestamp);

        // Staking to contract
        MarineBluesContract(_nftContract).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _tokenId);

        // Save staking information
        stakedTokens.push(
            StakedToken(msg.sender, _tokenId, _nftContract, timestamp, false)
        );

        // Increase in staking count
        totalStaked++;

        emit Stake(msg.sender, _tokenId, _nftContract, timestamp);
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx0Jm.png)

1. Make sure I have enough Ethereum
2. Make sure staking contract has enough Ethereum
3. Authorize the staking contract using setApprovalForAll so that it can transfer my NFTs

Gas Estimation error came out even after taking the above steps. I'm not sure why, but if you can guess or if I'm doing something wrong, please tell me. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that the `require()` condition validating `_nftContract.ownerOf()` doesn't fail, I'm assuming that your contract is correctly deployed on the same network as `_nftContract`.

`transferFrom()` can fail for several reasons. Most common causes might be:

- The token sender (specified in the first argument) didn't approve the transaction sender (in this case your contract) to operate this specific `_tokenId`
- The `_tokenId` does not belong to the token sender
- The `_tokenId` does not exist

Mind that you're executing the `transferFrom()` function from your contract - so the `msg.sender` (user executing `stake()` function) needs to give approval **directly** to `yourContract`.